# JMeter - Failed transaction account for average response time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In JMeter test, if any transaction takes long time to respond and then fails. Will that transaction be accounted in the calculation of average response time?

Answer (score 0):

It will, you can check it yourself using i.e. [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) and [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener combination:

[image]

If you don't want to see failed transactions in the results you can filter them out using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)